# Using PHPmailer To Send Mail To Thousands Simultaneously

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on a project for dispatching truck loads to subscribers so that they may try to get the cargo and make some money. My subscription service is going to be PHPmailer based.

Hypothetically let's say I have roughly 5000 subscribers. What would be the best way to send the emails simultaneously so that there isn't an unfair advantage as to go gets the email first vs someone who gets it 15 minutes later? I already have a working script for sending mail to different people without CC or BCC but I'm concerned with my site being marked as spam or a potential DDS attack.

What are my options? Would having a default email when a user signs up asking to be added to their address book work if the majority actually add?

I use GoDaddy as a host since that seems to matter sometimes.

I'm just concerned with being marked as spam or a potential attack site.

If I do need to create a delay, what would be the shortest delay possible while still being effective?

Comment: I think third party companies, that provide services like this are better choice https://zapier.com/learn/ultimate-guide-to-email-marketing-apps/best-transactional-email-sending-services/

Comment: @dav yeah i agree with what he said

Comment: Read into it. I like the idea of that Amazon one since my site is donation based and that seems cost effective. Have either of you used any of these services? If so what were the results and opinions?

Comment: 5000 is a trivial amount, but sending them is never going to happen simultaneously. It's nowhere near enough to be thought of as any kind of attack. It's not jut send speed that's an issue it's that delivery is not in your control, so there is little chance of it being "fair". Pretty much all ISPs use rate limiting, especially Yahoo, so you can never predict how long even a single message will take to deliver. GoDaddy is pretty much the bottom of the barrel as far as hosting goes.

Comment: Also, sending via any third party is not going to make any difference - messages will arrive in a pretty random order no matter how you send them.